# Group pandas data frame by quaters for plotting

Tags: python, pandas

Using pandas, how do I group datetime by quarter and year in one index column?

I'm able to group the date via: `df.groupby(by=[df.index.year, df.index.quarter])`.  However, since it creates two columns I get an error when I try to create a time series plot and I can't figure out how to fix this.

Here's an example:

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2016-1-1', '2016-4-1', '2016-7-1', '2016-10-1', '2017-1-1', '2017-4-1', '2017-7-1', '2017-10-1'], 
               'value':[32141,1234,2134,2134,1234,2134,213,1234]})

df0['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df0['date'], format="%Y-%m-%d")
df0.index = df0['date']
df0 = df0.groupby(by=[df0.index.year, df0.index.quarter]).sum()

df0
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of your data (like 8 lines) to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Bar chart - plot sum of values by a) year and b) quarter across all years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379670/python-bar-chart-plot-sum-of-values-by-a-year-and-b-quarter-across-all-year)

Comment: The answer in the possible duplicate above does not work for me.  I can group using 1 label, but when I try to group two labels I get the same date frame back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing here but maybe you are looking to apply a `transform()` to keep the rows. Try this example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'dates':pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2018-12-31'),
    'i': np.arange(365)
}).set_index('dates')

df.groupby(by=[df.index.year, df.index.quarter]).mean().plot(kind='bar')
df.groupby(by=[df.index.year, df.index.quarter]).transform('mean').plot()
```

Returns:

[image]